# Is there windows equivalent to the .bashrc file in linux?

Tags: windows, bashrc

Just discovered doskey emacs=emacs -nw $*, but without something like .bashrc, I'll have to type that every time I start a shell, right?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003/tool-for-commandline-bookmarks-on-windows) isn't identical, but the answer covers your scenario.

Comment: Not exactly what is asked for, but you might find [https://superuser.com/questions/1248999#1581575](https://superuser.com/questions/1248999#1581575) helpful. - Or else, have a look at the more elaborate answer [https://superuser.com/questions/144347#1446268](https://superuser.com/questions/144347#1446268).

Answer (score 98):

This is a very good question. I found [this](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html). I suppose you could make a cmd script and have it run when starting cmd :-?

```
; Run a command when CMD.exe starts
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"=-
```

EDIT:
I just tried it. I have `AutoRun=C:\mini\bashrc.cmd` and bashrc.cmd is

```
@echo off
set TEST_VAR=something
```

when I start cmd and enter `echo %TEST_VAR%` it says `something`. So it works :)

Comment: Small snippet I use: `doskey∙♦=exit` (where `♦` is `[char]4`). Enables you to close the shell with Ctrl+D, Enter.

Comment: This work great, nice job nc3b.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing +1

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor with 
AutoRun=%HOMEPATH%\bashrc.bat
So every user would have his own startup-sequence

Comment: I must be an idiot but where do I put this code?

Comment: @Marcel Just added an answer that explains this.

Comment: probably easiest to set to...  `AUTORUN=%USERPROFILE%\autorun.cmd` so that it will use one for the current user... cool trick though, will try it when I get home... I mostly use bash lately, but this would help.

Comment: Following @Joey's comment: you can enter `♦` in Notepad++ by opening Edit -> Character Panel and clicking on the character `EOT`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution edits the system-wide regkey, so user-specific profiles are difficult and may impede the use of cmd - does it cause terminating errors if a profile doesn't exist, for example?

Comment: Note that the documentation indicates that autorun instructions from both `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` are used, so if you need "for me only", use the latter (you probably need to create the `Command Processor` key yourself, first), and if you need universal-for-all-users, use the former. It's probably a good idea to edit the post to make that clear, and also mention that as autorun path you probably want a `%USERPROFILE%\cmd-autorun.bat` or something, because you want that file somewhere in your user profile dir.

Comment: @Tracker1 as cmd command without printing errors (i.e. when the script is missing): `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t REG_SZ /d @^%USERPROFILE^%\autorun.cmd" "2^>NUL /f`

Answer (score 25):

Modification of [nc3b's answer](https://superuser.com/a/144348/522206) for those who are windows noobs like myself.

Make a file in `C:\bashrc.cmd` or wherever you want your "rc" file to reside.

```
@echo off
set TEST_VAR=something
```

Run `regedit` by searching for it or running it in cmd.

In the folders on the left navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Right click on the `Command Processor` folder and click `New -> String Value`. Enter the key `AutoRun`. Double click on `AutoRun` and enter the bashrc location `C:\bashrc.cmd`.

Test:
Open a new cmd window and type:

```
echo %TEST_VAR%
```

if it says `something`, it works.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` and add the `/k` switch to run a certain .bat file on startup, something like this:

```
cmd.exe /k "%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\cmd-startup.bat"
```

`cmd-startup.bat` in your home dir would then work just like `.bashrc`

Comment: But know that [cmd has both a global and local regkey it consults](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) for `AutoRun` functionality that you can use to run things without having to build shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your shell is Powershell, not cmd, you can create a *profile* for your shell. Such profiles basically are scripts which are executed when you start a shell. Just like `.bashrc`. An important part of [this post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx) might be the following:

> The locations (on Windows Vista) of the profiles for the powershell.exe
>   host are as follows:
>
> - **`%windir%\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`**
>     This is for all users of the computer and for all shells.
> - **`%windir%\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.Power­Shell_profile.ps1`**
>     This is for all users of the computer, but it is only for the
>     Microsoft.PowerShell shell.
> - **`%UserProfile%\Documents\Windows­PowerShell\profile.ps1`**
>     This is for the current user only and all shells.
> - **`%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Micro­soft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`**
>     This is for the current user only and only for the Microsoft.PowerShell
>     shell.
>
> These profiles aren't created by default. They exist only if you create
>   them.

It seems to be the same on Windows 7, 8 and 10. You can also find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28VS.85%29.aspx).

---

**Note:** You may need to run the following. Otherwise, your profile may not be executed.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

You can also run the following as administrator to change the configuration for all users.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 4):

To all people coming from a unix-like world and landing on this question (i.e. everybody, since it asks about `.bashrc`): ***Radically* improve your Windows console life and stop using stock `cmd.exe` and the default Windows terminal!!**  *No one asking this question, or looking at answers to this question, should be using the current default `cmd.exe` and terminal!*

If willing to switch off of stock `cmd.exe` (I know of no valid reason not to), one simple answer to the original question is:

Install and use [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) and your `.bashrc` equivalent becomes 
`%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd`, while also *significantly* improving your shell/console experience.

Opinions, extensions, and loosely related recommendations follow...

---

Cmder is a metapackage that packages up [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu), [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink), and a pile of extra settings and stuff. ConEmu is the terminal emulator that provides the startup script capability, which (through the [default ConEmu settings Cmder provides](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Cmder-vs.-ConEmu)) ends up routing to the indicated `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd`.

*You may want to just explicitly use ConEmu and Clink independently, rather than use the bundled Cmder package.*

To do that, and to add in some more "gotta work on windows, what should I do" bliss, below are some good/opinionated things to do. These are admittedly VERY loosely related to the initial question, but I've recently been through a Windows setup again, have typed up most of this already, and the target audience in this question is correct, so here you go...

1. Use [scoop.sh](https://scoop.sh) for *all* your installs

   - scoop is a great package manager for windows (similar to apt/yum/pacman/emerge/whatever)... where all packages install to the user (with no admin privileges needed)
   - definitely install the `extras` bucket for many non-console things (`scoop bucket add extras`)
   - you can also use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), but (my opinion) only if under duress and the thing you want is not in a scoop bucket
   - or just make your own scoop manifest
   - it is sad day when the thing I want isn't in a scoop bucket :(
   - unlike scoop, chocolatey needs admin privileges for its installs
2. Use [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink) as your shell instead of `cmd.exe`

   - `scoop install clink`
   - gives you GNU readline goodness (like ctrl-r, ctrl-s cmd history navigation) and more
   - be sure to also `clink autorun install` to make it run when `cmd.exe` is run
3. Use [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) as your terminal emulator

   - `scoop install conemu`
   - the Windows terminal is *terrible* (but they are [working on it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/))
   - be sure to configure it as the default terminal

     - "Force ConEmu" and "Register on OS startup" in `Settings::Integration->Default term`
   - SO MANY other configuration possibilities

     - if overwhelmed, maybe just stick with [Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) and its reasonable defaults (`scoop install cmder`), but I personally think it is cleaner to install/run Clink and ConEmu separately.
4. Install [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) (like, *right now*)

   - `scoop install gow`
   - > [100 GNU tools](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/executables_list) (`grep`, `vim`, `sed`, `ls`, `cat`, `curl`, `wc`, `less`, `find`, etc, etc) you know and love, directly in your `cmd.exe`-like terminal without non-native weirdness
   - watch for name-collision renames like `find->gfind` and `awk->gawk`
   - I use Gow pretty much exclusively for basic Windows work instead of mucking with WSL, Cygwin, MSYS, git bash,  etc.
   - Gow tools get as close to the GNU/*nix-on-Windows as I've experienced so far while staying native to Windows, without the headaches of Cygwin environments, WSL filesystem nastiness (which also [being worked on](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)), gitbash windows, etc
5. Install other handy tools as you see fit (with scoop)

   - the [main](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/tree/master/bucket) and [extras](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras) scoop buckets have *many* more good tools and applications (python, openssh, ripgrep, fzf, sysinternals, sublime-text, meld, ccleaner, etc)

     - although definitely not a GNU/unix thing, [sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals) is an essential/classic collection of Windows native tools.
   - use `scoop search` and `scoop info` to find the ones you want, or browse the buckets (there are [several buckets](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/blob/master/buckets.json), not just main and extras)

Comment: Couldn't find manifest for 'conemu'

Comment: the new version "windows terminal" is a huge leap forward.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/terminal/

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx

To expound on Martin's solution (the shortcut), here's the PowerShell equivalent.

**NOTE**: You will need to have PowerShell script execution enabled. If this is disabled, you'll need to run an elevated PowerShell and execute `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`. Obviously, this is not recommended for security reasons, but there ya go.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -File "%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\ps-startup.ps1"
```

Have a file named `ps-startup.ps1` in your user directory and your shortcut will execute it as a PowerShell file on startup. Just run PowerShell with this shortcut from here on out.

Comment: This can be achieved in a "better" way through powershell profiles. You can find the location of your current profile by: echo $profile . You can add lines to that file, and that should do it for future sessions. For existing sessions, you can reload the profile with: & $profile .

Answer (score 3):

Basically nc3b's answer works, but Chocolatey's [DevBox-Common](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Devbox-Common) package will **make it easier**.

1. If you have not already installed Chocolatey, [install it.](https://chocolatey.org/)
2. Install DevBox-Common package by `choco install devbox-common -y`

   - You should type this command inside **administrative** cmd.exe or PowerShell.
3. Now you have `.bashrc.bat` and `.bashrc.include.aliases-common.bat` in your home path. Every file matching `.bashrc.include.*.bat` will be executed at every command shell start.

Answer (score 1):

This answer can't be the replacement of whole feature of .bashrc but you can create alias in windows as easy as you could do in linux.

Create a directory lets say `C:\commands`, add this directory to Path Variable and inside the directory create a file `cmdrc.bat`.

Add the below codes to your cmdrc.bat file

```
set filename=%~1
set command=%~2

echo @echo off > C:\commands\%filename%.bat
echo %command% >> C:\commands\%filename%.bat
```

Now every time you have to create an alias like
`alias ls=dir`

you can run the command
 `cmdrc ls dir`

every time you'll run this command it will create a new bat file in C:\commands directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the registry key from commandline itself (and thus avoid the regedit part) with :

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "Autorun" /t REG_SZ /d "%"USERPROFILE"%"\cmd-startup.bat
```

Comment: You mean `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (which uses `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, not `REG_SZ`). What you're showing is the _global_ autorun key, which you definitely don't want to be setting anything for.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `macros.doskey` file I think or a `macro.cmd` something like that.

I made a repo that is [garbage](https://github.com/garbageoverflow/cmd-macros) and has a lot of macros. I made a installation walkthrough, but it's too complicated

Answer (score 0):

I just create some junk script, but it works. Just create .cmdrc in your user folder and if you start command prompt from code bellow, you run .cmdrc lines as commands.

```
cmd.exe /K "(echo @echo off & type %USERPROFILE%\.cmdrc & echo. & echo cls & echo @cmd.exe) > %tmp%\cmdrc.bat & cmd.exe /K "call %tmp%\cmdrc.bat""
```

And if you paste this into windows terminal, you could use this as default command instead of plain cmd.exe.