# Can I create Windows command prompt custom commands?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Is there any way I can enable `Ctrl+D` to exit the command prompt, like we do in Unix?

I know that I can set an alias by using `doskey`, but as we use `Ctrl+D` or other in Unix, I also want to use this in the Windows command prompt.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Unix, the line editing capabilities are part of the *Windows console* windows, not the shell. Because of this, the `cmd.exe` shell can simply read the input line-by-line and does not perform *any* special interpretation of your key presses – even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> will be treated as any other command. You can even make a *doskey* alias for it:

```
doskey CtrlD=exit
```

---

Windows *does* have an "EOF" control character, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, which works similarly to Ctrl-D in Unix; however, it won't work in this case since `cmd.exe` simply keeps reading even if hits EOF.

Comment: really ? "doskey Ctrl D=exit" will work ?

Comment: You can do it using `doskey`, but entering `Ctrl+D` isn't easy. The full command is `doskey ?=exit` where you have to replace `?` with the character of control code 4. You will need an editor that lets you enter special characters. For example in Vim, you would type (in insert mode) `Ctrl+V`, `4`, `Enter`.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: Unless you just enter it in the command line.

Comment: @grawity: Didn't think about that :) I always put this kind of stuff in some kind of startup script (see [this thread](http://superuser.com/a/144348/115443) for a Windows equivalent of `.bashrc`). Thanks for pointing out the direct way, though!

Comment: Entering `Ctrl+D` is pretty straightforward, actually, if you have a keyboard with a numpad: Hold `Alt`, press `004` on the keypad, release `Alt`. You can enter any ASCII character this way; it'll work with some Unicode (use the decimal value for the desired character), but I think many symbols are localization dependent.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use 'exit'?  It works on Windows and Unix/Linux.

Comment: it takes four letters to type 'exit', while ctrl+d is considered as shortcuts. That's why we call them shortcuts so that we dont need to type the whole command.

Answer (score 0):

Since cmd.exe is one of the main and basic applications for windows OS, it is highly unlikely for you to be able to tamper with it, since it is probably

- Hard coded in application
- Restricted due to possible security issues (imagine if viruses could tamper with it)

You can always just use alternative tools for these options, or make one of your own. There should be some kind of application that would global change that by pressing `ctrl + D` you mean `ctrl + C`, thou it is probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

there are two shortcuts which will work out of the box: `alt+f4` or `alt+space, C` both work with ALL windows.

Comment: do you really call "alt+space, C" as shortcut ?, and also AFAIK alt+f4 doesnt work for command prompt

Comment: alt+space c does, and do you really balk at the need to hit the c key?