# Why does `ls` work on my cmd? (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, bash

I'm running windows 7, it's old and I have messed around with it a bit. When I'm in cmd I find that `ls` works just like I would expect it to in Linux. So do a few other commands such as `mv` and `rm`. This isn't an issue in itself, but I would like to know where they are coming from. As far as I know Windows does not support these automatically. I probably added them myself at some point. Is there any way I can try and devise why they are working?

Comment: Concerning the current tag [windows-7]. The ['windows' tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/windows/info) says:
"For questions not specific to a single version of Microsoft Windows. Otherwise, use a more specific tag such as [windows-7] or [windows-10].".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `cmd` you can use the `where` command to find the location of an executable:

```
where ls
```

This is similar to the Unix `which` command, and like `which` it does not report internal commands and aliases. It also has additional options not in `which`.

If it's one of the Unix commands you have imported, you can use `which` itself.

Comment: The response I get to this is `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ls.exe` So I guess that's where stuff is coming from. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might have installed Git repository. This might be from your C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe

Answer (score 2):

https://superuser.com/questions/1248999#1581575

The original poster has already confirmed that the source in their case is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ls.exe`.

But as suggested by *Shanmugam*, the reason unix commands run in the
*Windows* command line, `cmd`, might be that you have GitBash installed.

If so, when `ls` runs from the command line, a likely source is
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe`.

You might have installed GitBash from
https://git-scm.com/download/win or
https://gitforwindows.org/.

When installing GitBash, the path `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` is not
added by default to the `PATH` environment variable. So you may want to
do this yourself, as follows.
Hit the <kbd>win</kbd> key on your keyboard, and then paste or type `envi`.
Click on `Edit the system environment variables`. Click on the button down
to the right named <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>.
In the `System variables` frame, scroll down and double-click on `PATH` as
in the figure below.

[image: Environment Variables > System variables > PATH]

A new window opens. Click on the <kbd>New</kbd> button and then paste or
type
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`. Click yourself out (three times on
<kbd>OK</kbd>).

Please note that you need to close and restart `cmd.exe` (the terminal
window) for the changes to take effect.
The emulated Unix commands in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` should now
work from anywhere in the command line.

Having read this far, chances are that you will want to consider
installing
[Clink](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/releases/download/0.4.9/clink_0.4.9_setup.exe)
as well.