# How to get bash commands in CLink

Tags: command-line, bash, clink

Some time ago I installed [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) on one PC and it supports bash commands, like `pwd, ls`. Now I installed it on another PC and these commands are not recognized. Other features of clink, like auto-completion, reverse-i-search, prompt color are still supported. The versions of Clink on both machines are the same: 0.4.9. I checked installation folder, settings on both PCs and its also the same. Both PCs are Windows 10. I don't remember what I did to have support for these commands, I think I did nothing special - I got them right out of the box. Does anyone know how to make clink support bash commands?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with CLink per se. See if [https://superuser.com/questions/1248999/why-does-ls-work-on-my-cmd-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1248999/why-does-ls-work-on-my-cmd-windows) is of any help. You may find that both answers to that question are helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`ls\` work on my cmd? (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/1248999/why-does-ls-work-on-my-cmd-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Clink at all, but it seems it's just [Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) for `cmd.exe`. It does not provide commands; it handles command line editing, command history, completions, keyboard shortcuts.

I guess the first PC got `pwd` and `ls` (or rather `pwd.exe` and `ls.exe`) from elsewhere, e.g. from Cygwin. If proper executables with such names are available in `PATH` then they will be recognized *with or without* Clink.

---

Side note: while `pwd` is a standard builtin in Bash, `ls` is not. Strictly: Bash does support dynamically loadable builtins, so one can implement `ls` as a builtin; but usually it's not a builtin. Therefore calling `ls` a "bash command" is a misunderstanding. It's a standalone command.

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed Git from
https://git-scm.com/download/win or
https://gitforwindows.org/.
When `pwd` runs from your windows command line, a likely source is
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\pwd.exe`.

By default `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` is not added to your `PATH`
environment variable, so you may want to do this yourself, as follows.
Hit the <kbd>win</kbd> key on your keyboard, and then paste or type
`envi`. Click on `Edit the system environment variables`. Click on
the button down to the right named <kbd>Environment Variables...</kbd>.
In the `System variables` frame, scroll down and double-click on `PATH`
as in the figure below.

[image: Environment Variables > System variables > PATH]

A window titled `Edit environment variable` opens. Click on the
<kbd>New</kbd> button and then paste or type `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.
Click yourself out (three times on <kbd>OK</kbd>).

Please note that you need to close and restart `cmd.exe`
(the terminal window) for the changes to take effect.

The emulated Unix commands in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` should now
work from anywhere in the command line.