# Why file content is not remain after unmount a drive in linux?

Tags: linux, cmd.exe, bashrc, autorun, unmount

I wrote a script on `bashrc.cmd` from my **windows 10** to activate my **virtual environment** automatically. I pointed the path of **bashrc.cmd** into `AutoRun` according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux).

***bashrc.cmd***

```
@echo off
CD dev-env\Scripts && activate.bat && CD .. && CD ..
SET APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

The script was running well with --

```
CD dev-env\Scripts && activate.bat && CD .. && CD ..
```

I stacked and completely unable to do anything on my **windows 10** for the following lines of code [especially for **start** line] --

```
@echo off
REM CD dev-env\Scripts && activate.bat && CD .. && CD ..
start "" /D "\dev-env\Scripts\" /B activate.bat
SET APP_SETTINGS="config.DevelopmentConfig"
```

I reboot my machine and trying to edit with **bashrc.cmd** from my **linux os**. I was unable to edit this **bashrc.cmd** script due to the fact of ***mount - unmount and Read Only***. Then I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) and able to change successfully [keeping the previous script].

***Problem***

The **bashrc.cmd** file does not remain as updated when I unmount and remount again. So, how do I change the content permanently even after unmount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was a bit **tricky** which is directly linked with mount / unmount. Let's first check the list of available drives in a machine --

```
sudo fdisk -l
lsblk
```

You may get **`sdXY`** (X = a, b, c ... and Y = 1, 2, 3 ...). I was tried mount on with --

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8
```

I got an error like this --

```
Unlike in case of  read-only  mount,  the  read-write  mount  is
denied  if  the  NTFS  volume is hibernated. One needs either to
resume Windows and shutdown it  properly,  or  use  this  option
which  will  remove  the  Windows hibernation file. Please note,
this means that the saved Windows  session  will  be  completely
lost. Use this option under your own responsibility.
```

I just shut down windows pc before login into it. After that, I boot my pc with linux and remove **bashrc.cmd** file. Now my pc is now working from boot sides. Have a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) for better understanding.