# Windows command line alias commands

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'd like to open multiple chrome profiles at once, what is the easiest way to do that from the windows command line? I'm thinking something like `open 43, 41, 1` (where the #'s refer to the --profile-directory) would run the following command

`start chrome --profile-directory="Profile 43" && start chrome --profile-directory="Profile 41" && start chrome --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

I've seen this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux) but imagine there is a much simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do so with a one-liner `open.bat` file:

```
for %%x in (%*) do start chrome --profile-directory="Profile %%~x"
```

Use it as:

```
open 43 41 1
```

Arguments containing blanks will need to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: perfect, thank you