# Equivalent to export command in .bashrc in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I would like to be able to make a script in Windows and make it runnable from anywhere in the command line.

For example, if I made a script 'touch' mimicking the command from UNIX, how could I make it globally available? I saw another similar question that used the 'doskey' command, but in the answer it seemed like you would have to manually run a script each time you loaded cmd.exe to get the other scripts into the environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there windows equivalent to the .bashrc file in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/144348) uses AutoRun to run a self made script where you can set variables.

Comment: Generally when an answer on another question on the site applies to a question, you should flag the question as a duplicate of the other question.