# Where is the location of the script that runs every time cmd.exe is executed in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Recently, I uninstalled Anaconda 3, an early "02" version of the year 2020. The uninstallation process left the Command Prompt as well as the Power Shell (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) in a strange situation: These shells would run and execute a script that mentions Anaconda 3 location and the Conda executable every time when starting cmd.exe, for example.

My question is quite general, regardless of Anaconda 3, where is the location in Windows where we can see which script runs each time the cmd.exe is executed?

Thanks.

Comment: [Is there windows equivalent to the .bashrc file in linux?](https://superuser.com/a/1045659/687987)